# redirect output of loop to current reading file

Tags: shell, awk

I have simple script that looks like

```
for file in `ls -rlt *.rules | awk '{print $9}'`
do
cat $file | awk -F"|" -v DATE=$(date +%Y"_"%m"_"%d) '!$3{$3=DATE} !$4{$4=DATE} 1' OFS="|" $file
done
```

How can i redirect output of awk to the same file which it is reading to perform action.

files have data before running above script

```
123|test||
```

After running script files should have data like

```
123|test|2017_04_05|2017_04_05
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot replace your files on the fly like this, mostly because you **increase their size**.

The way is to use temporary file, then replace the current:

```
for file in `ls -1 *.rules `
do
  TMP_FILE=/tmp/${file}_$$
  awk -F"|" -v DATE=$(date +%Y"_"%m"_"%d) '!$3{$3=DATE} !$4{$4=DATE} 1' OFS="|" $file > ${TMP_FILE}
  mv ${TMP_FILE} $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would modify [Michael Vehrs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226913/451601) otherwise good answer as follows:

```
ls -rt *.rules | while read file
do
    TMP_FILE="/tmp/${file}_$$"
    awk -F"|" -v DATE=$(date +%Y"_"%m"_"%d) \
        '!$3{$3=DATE} !$4{$4=DATE} 1' OFS="|" "$file" > "$TMP_FILE"
    mv "$TMP_FILE" "$file"
done
```

Your question uses **ls**(1) to sort the files by time, oldest first.  The above preserves that property.  I removed the {} braces because they add nothing in a shell script if the variable name isn't being interpolated, and quotes to cope with filenames that include whitespace.

If time-order doesn't matter, I'd consider an inside-out solution: in awk, write to a temporary file instead of standard output, and then rename it with `system` in an `END` block.  Then if something goes wrong your input is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is silly to use a combination of `ls -rlt` and `awk` when the only thing you need is the file name. You don't even need `ls` because the **shell glob** is expanded by the **shell**, not `ls`. Simply use `for file in *.rules`. Since the date would seem to be the same for every file (unless you run the command at midnight), it is sufficient to calculate it in advance:

```
date=$(date +%Y"_"%m"_"%d)
for file in *.rules
do
    TMP_FILE=$(mktemp ${file}_XXXXXX)
    awk -F"|" -v DATE=${date} '!$3{$3=DATE} !$4{$4=DATE} 1' OFS="|" $file > ${TMP_FILE}
    mv ${TMP_FILE} $file
done
```

However, since `awk` also knows which file it is reading, you could do something like this:

```
awk -F"|" -v DATE=$(date +%Y"_"%m"_"%d) \
    '!$3{$3=DATE} !$4{$4=DATE} { print > FILENAME ".tmp" }' OFS="|" *.rules
rename .tmp "" *.rules.tmp
```